# Lua - how to simulate "multithreading"?

Tags: multithreading, function, lua

I have 2 functions:

```
function func1()
   while true do
       -- listen on connection
   end
end

function func2()
   while true do
       -- execute other code
   end
end
```

I want to run both functions "simultaneously" while sharing variables between them. I have tried to create a dispatcher that makes a coroutine with the two functions but I can't think of a way to schedule them to quickly alternate their execution. (func1 runs for a second, func2 runs for a second, func1 runs for a second, and so on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua does not support asynchronous multithreading. It only supports *cooperative* threading. That means the two "threads" have to be *designed* to give the other thread time to execute. Such designs are usually highly dependent on what you're trying to accomplish.

Your example talks about one thread listening for a connection and the other thread doing something (either with data from that connection or not; it's not exactly clear). In such a system, it would be a good idea to have `func1` invoke the thread for `func2` when the connection hasn't provided new data. And `func2` would return control back to `func1` only when it has finished processing something.

But there is no one-size-fits-all solution to cooperative multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

There exist C libraries for Lua which expose methods for multithreading or multiprocessing.  Some examples would be

- [MPI for Lua](https://colberg.org/lua-mpi/)
- [lua-llthread](https://github.com/Neopallium/lua-llthreads)
- [Lua 5.1 pthread](http://lua51pthread.luaforge.net/)
- [lua---parallel](https://github.com/clementfarabet/lua---parallel) (apparently (?) depends on Torch)
- Torch has some [parallel methods](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/containers.md#nn.Parallel)

All of these are third-party solution and, as the other answer explains, there are no built-in capabilities for asynchronous multithreading in Lua.

I think [lua-llthread](https://github.com/Neopallium/lua-llthreads) would come closest to what you describe.  It supports communication between threads via ZeroMQ.